# Trying to add a blank space after a column in PowerQuery with OLE

Tags: excel, powerquery, ole, dbase

I am trying to do what seems like the most simple thing.  I want to take a column in PowerQuery and add a space after.  I then am going to CombineColumns (I need the space for formatting).  I have tried 3 or 4 methods and numerous syntax (about 3 days trying to track this down).  I'm doing this out of dBase using OLE.  No errors but it is blanking out the entire column.

```
qString1 = 'let Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents('+'"'+_app.session.oRep.outputfilename+'"'+'), [Implementation='+'"'+"1.2"+'"'+']), ;
step11 = Source{[Id='+'"'+"Page001"+'"'+']}[Data], ;
step21= Table.SplitAt(step11,2), ;
step31=List.Last(step21), ;
step41 = Table.PromoteHeaders(step31, [PromoteAllScalars=true]), ;
step51 = Table.TransformColumns(step41,{"'+Column1Name+'", each ['+Column1Name+']+" "}) in step51'
```

Column1Name is a variable name for the column header.  I have tried to hard code the column name as well as +"ABC".  It all blanks out the column.  It works perfectly through step41.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generically the method would be

```
= Table.TransformColumns(PriorStep,{{"ColumnName", each _ & " ", type text}})
```

so for yours, where Column1Name is a variable name for the column header, try

```
step51 = Table.TransformColumns(step41,{{Column1Name, each _ & " ", type text}})
in step51
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think it was the & instead of the +.